# Using Expression to 'Cast' Func<object, object> to Func<T, TRet>

Tags: c#, closures, expression

I've written a little function that attempts to do the following dynamically:

```
        Func<object, object> fa = i => Convert.ChangeType(i, typeof (string));
        Func<int, string> fb = o => (string) fa((int)o);
```

The func is as follows:

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     Converts <see cref="Func{object, object}" /> to <see cref="Func{T, TResult}" />.
    /// </summary>
    public static Delegate Convert(Func<object, object> func, Type argType, Type resultType)
    {
        Contract.Requires(func != null);
        Contract.Requires(resultType != null);

        var param = Expression.Parameter(argType);

        var converted = Expression.Convert(
            Expression.Call(func.Method, Expression.Convert(param, typeof (object))),
            resultType);

        var delegateType = typeof (Func<,>).MakeGenericType(argType, resultType);
        return Expression.Lambda(delegateType, converted, param).Compile();
    }
```

Now this works ok when there is no closure involved - this test passes:

```
    [Test]
    public void When_Converting_Without_Closure_Then_Suceeds()
    {
        // Arrange
        Func<object, object> f = i => Convert.ChangeType(i, typeof(string));            
        var sut = FuncConversion.Convert(f, typeof(int), typeof(string));

        // Act
        var res = (string) sut.DynamicInvoke(10);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(typeof(Func<int, string>), sut.GetType());
        Assert.AreEqual("10", res);
    }
```

but when a closure is involved, this test fails:

```
    [Test]
    public void When_Converting_With_Closure_Then_Succeeds()
    {
        // Arrange
        var typeTo = typeof (string);
        Func<object, object> f = i => Convert.ChangeType(i, typeTo);            
        var sut = FuncConversion.Convert(f, typeof(int), typeof(string));

        // Act
        var res = (string)sut.DynamicInvoke(10);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(typeof(Func<int, string>), sut.GetType());
        Assert.AreEqual("10", res);
    }
```

System.ArgumentException : Static method requires null instance, non-static method requires non-null instance.
Parameter name: method
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateStaticOrInstanceMethod(Expression instance, MethodInfo method)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(MethodInfo method, Expression arg0)

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Ok I think I know whats going on, there is a hidden closure param for the func and I don't know about its existence. Going to try Expression.Invoke.

Comment: Any reason to do it this way, rather than with a very simple method: `private static Func<T1,T2> Convert<T1,T2>(Func<object,object> func) { return t => (T2)func(t); }`? You could then do `var sut = Convert<int,string>(f);`

Comment: yeah, I don't have T1/T2 as generic params. I could invoke that method dynamically I guess, although that will have an overhead everytime its invoked which isn't great given these can be invoked a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok fixed it. The problem is that with a closure, a func which is normally a static method, has its first param, which would be the target instance on an instance method, used to hold the closure state. So I need to check if that state is there and invoke with it if it is.

Et voila:

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     Converts <see cref="Func{object, object}" /> to <see cref="Func{T, TResult}" />.
    /// </summary>
    public static Delegate Convert(Func<object, object> func, Type argType, Type resultType)
    {
        // If we need more versions of func then consider using params Type as we can abstract some of the
        // conversion then.

        Contract.Requires(func != null);
        Contract.Requires(resultType != null);

        var param = Expression.Parameter(argType);
        var convertedParam = new Expression[] {Expression.Convert(param, typeof (object))};

        // This is gnarly... If a func contains a closure, then even though its static, its first
        // param is used to carry the closure, so its as if it is not a static method, so we need
        // to check for that param and call the func with it if it has one...
        Expression call;
        call = Expression.Convert(
            func.Target == null
            ? Expression.Call(func.Method, convertedParam) 
            : Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(func.Target), func.Method, convertedParam), resultType);

        var delegateType = typeof (Func<,>).MakeGenericType(argType, resultType);
        return Expression.Lambda(delegateType, call, param).Compile();
    }
```