# How to convert Expression<Func<TSource,string>> to Expression<Func<object,string>>

Tags: c#, expression, func

I am creating an expression dynamically which I pass into some method but that method accepts that expression in different way. It throws exception:

```
Object of type
'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Common.Domain.ViewModels.Dealer.CustomerGridViewModel,System.String]]'
cannot be converted to type
'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[System.Object,System.String]]'
```

I have tried the answer from [Using Expression to 'Cast' Func<object, object> to Func<T, TRet>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590685/using-expression-to-cast-funcobject-object-to-funct-tret/16592100) but that is not working for me.

My expression is

```
Expression<Func<CustomerViewModel, string>>
```

but I want result as

```
Expression<Func<object, string>>
```

Comment: So I convert your `Expression<Func<CustomerViewModel, string>>` to a `Expression<Func<object, string>>` and then invoke it with a `Foo`. `Foo` isn't a `CustomerViewModel` nor anything related to it. What's the logic inside the `Func` meant to do with it? It was expecting a `CustomerViewModel` or something derived from it.

Comment: Actually I am sending this expression to a method at run time and it expects expression as Expression<Func<object,string>> instead where object will be used as source which will be used further as of type CustomerViewModel. That is why its required conversion before sending. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the fact that such cast is dangerous as the target method isn't guaranteed to operate only on `CustomerViewModel`, the following code makes adapter expression which accepts a parameter of `Object` type, tries to cast it to the `CustomerViewModel` and calls the original expression internally:

```
var objParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
var call = Expression.Invoke(inputExpression, Expression.Convert(objParam, typeof(Foo)));
var outputExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, string>>(call, objParam);
```

where `inputExpression` is an original expression of type `Expression<Func<CustomerViewModel, string>>` and `outputExpression` is new expression of type `Expression<Func<object, string>>` which can be passed to your method.

Comment: It worked like a charm. You are the champ buddy, thanks for your guidance